# To change the html hyperlink to asp format

Tags: asp-classic

this is my html code :

```vb
 <td align="left"><a href="<%=mLink%>"><%=adoRecordset("JobNo")%></a>
```

and how do i change it to asp  like :

```
mHTML = mHTML & "<td>" & "mLink" & adoRecordset("JobNo") & "</a></td>"
```

(this code was wrong and could someone help me to make it right ) thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to print a `"` , use `""` within asp code.

```
mHTML = mHTML & "<td align=""left""><a href=""" & mLink & """>"& adoRecordset("JobNo") & "</a></td>"
```